# Webdriver is not working when calling the recorded functions in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have the following code:

```java
@Test
public void testNewaudit1() throws Exception 
{
    driver.get(baseUrl + "public/login"); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Emp0001");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Emp0001");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Company (GST)")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Regular")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("company_name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("company_name")).sendKeys("vel and company");
    driver.findElement(By.id("phoneno1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("phoneno1")).sendKeys("9865320147");
    driver.findElement(By.id("cemail")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("cemail")).sendKeys("dfhgdsj@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("aphoneno")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("aphoneno")).sendKeys("9876544321");
    driver.findElement(By.id("cgstno")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("cgstno")).sendKeys("27AASCS2460H1Z0");
    driver.findElement(By.id("cweblink")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("cweblink")).sendKeys("www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("cpanno")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("cpanno")).sendKeys("ABCDE1234F");
    driver.findElement(By.id("image2")).clear();
}
```

I used `id` functions inside the code, but when running the script, `id` functions are not working and I get this error:

[image: Error message]

When using the selenium IDE tool, the same script runs without any error but using the selenium Web_driver error caused.

How can I fix this?

Comment: May be you need to update your selenium webdriver version.

Comment: It looks to me like the error is in the driver initialization itself.  Show your driver initialization code.

Comment: You are having an alert during your test execution and it is not been handled.